# Why use a Messenger rather than passing the reference to a Handler?

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

I have a main activity and bound service. The bound service receives a command from the network, which triggers a Message to be sent to a Handler in the main activity. I got everything to work by passing the Handler's reference to the service. And then... I stumbled across this thing called a [Messenger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html).

> **Messenger:** Reference to a Handler, which others can use to send messages to it. This allows for the implementation of message-based communication across processes, by creating a Messenger pointing to a Handler in one process, and handing that Messenger to another process.

This inspired a few questions:

- Does the term process mean I won't need to use a Messenger unless I
  generate a separate process under the [Process and Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)
  guidelines?
- Is it always good practice to use a Messenger?
- Is passing a reference to the Handler typically a bad idea?

Comment: This is not an answer for your question, but I suggest that you should use AsyncTask for background threads. (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I'm using a bound IntentService, which should handle the asynchronous requests. I don't think an AsyncTask is appropriate, because the documentation states _"AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)"_, while my service is listening for commands from the Internet and may run for the entire lifetime of the activity.

Comment: Also as a side comment, AsyncTasks must be invoked from the UI thread

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does the term process mean I won't need to use a Messenger unless I
>   generate a separate process under the Process and Thread guidelines?

This is correct. You need a `Messenger` if you want to bind a remote service (e.g. running in another process). In this case, the only option to provide remote service with a pointer to your `Handler` would be to use a `Messenger`.

> Is it always good practice to use a Messenger?

I would not say so. Use it when it's really needed - for remote services or if you start service without binding it. You can pack `Messenger` as an extra into an `Intent` and start service with it. Thus you can pass reference to a `Handler` without binding a service. This is another case when `Messenger` is useful.

> Is passing a reference to the Handler typically a bad idea?

If you properly handle registration and unregistration of `Handler` when activity starts and stops, then you should be ok. There is no need to use `Messenger` for local service then. If you don't unregister handler properly, there will be memory leaks (service refers a handler, and handler refers a stopped activity).

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of Messenger over handler is, Messenger is able to queue all the messages sent from various clients. While Handler needs a looper to do that. So messenger gives an extra edge when used in IPC among remote processes